# How to post input fields conditionally

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, kendo-dropdown

I have an MVC (Razor) web app. The form has 2 fields, one dropdown box (Kendo) and one input field for a date.

After the user makes a change on the dropdown, my 2nd input field is enabled or disabled based on the chosen type in the dropdown box. When the input field is disabled I fill the input with a default value.

When the user submits the form, I only get 2nd form field value posted in the viewmodel when the 2nd field is enabled, when disabled the value is not posted. I know this a common pattern in HTML, that disabled fields are not part of the POST.

My question: how can I solve this issue to get the value POSTed when the field is disabled ? It should be done in JS...

Comment: Can you show your working code? So it will be easier for us to give an answer. Are you posting through JS or are you using @Html.BeginForm?

Comment: Post is by a regular submit button using beginform in Razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, in the onchange handler of the dropdown box attach this JS code:

```
var defaultDateValue = "2017-01-04"; //just for demo
var $effectiveToInput = $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.EffectiveToDate)");
$effectiveToInput.parent().append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"@Html.NameFor(m => m.EffectiveToDate)\" id=\"@Html.NameFor(m => m.EffectiveToDate)\" value=\"" + defaultDateValue +"\" />");
```

And for the other types, i clear the hidden fields with checks:

```
function removeHiddenEffectiveToDateField() {
    var $effectiveToInput = $("#@(Html.IdFor(m => m.EffectiveToDate))[type = hidden]");
    if (null !== $effectiveToInput) {
       $effectiveToInput.remove();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, what i did was, created a class , which would make the text box appear like disabled, by removing mouse events and styling a bit

```
[https://codepen.io/DawsonMediaD/pen/Dqrck][1]
```

or

Bit tricky, just before the post , enable all of them